# How to print a value in debugger in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<script> var url = std.setUrl(); alert(url); </script>
```

The above code gives an alert instead of printing it to a debugger.

Comment: use console.log(url) instead of alert(url)

Comment: I tried that too it doesn't print it in NativeApp

Comment: What do you mean by NativeApp ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
  console.log(std.setUrl());
</script>
```

Comment: Does this display in nativeapp